# renderMenu resulting in strange formatting, R Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

I am creating a sidebar menu from the Server of my Shiny app, but the formatting of the server-generated menu doesn't match with the menu created in the UI.

I have tried some shinyjs hide/show functions after assigning a div() to the menu which also ends up with an odd, non-matching format. I think renderMenu is probably the better path. I would prefer not to 'hack' with CSS, but any help is appreciated.

Here's a working script:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Header'),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem('First Menu', tabName = 'first_menu'),
        menuSubItem('sub1', tabName = 'sub_1'),
        menuSubItem('sub2', tabName = 'sub_2'),
      uiOutput('server_menu')
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$server_menu <- renderMenu({
    list(
      menuItem('Second Menu', tabName = 'second_menu'),
               menuSubItem('sub3', tabName = 'sub_3'),
               menuSubItem('sub4', tabName = 'sub_4')
              )
  }) 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Which produces this result:

[image]

Any advice on how I can solve this would be awesome!  Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `uiOutput`, use `menuItemOutput`. Also, your hierarchy of `menuItem` and `menuSubItem` seems to be incorrect. `menuSubItem` should be child of `menuItem`

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = 'Header'),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem(
                'First Menu', 
                tabName = 'first_menu',
                menuSubItem('sub1', tabName = 'sub_1'),
                menuSubItem('sub2', tabName = 'sub_2')
            ),
            menuItemOutput('server_menu') # Changed from uiOuput to menuItemOutput
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$server_menu <- renderMenu({
        list(
            # modified hierarchies
            menuItem(
                'Second Menu', 
                tabName = 'second_menu',
                menuSubItem('sub3', tabName = 'sub_3'),
                menuSubItem('sub4', tabName = 'sub_4')
            )
        )
    }) 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]